# Как подобрать регулярное выражения для поиска абзацев между конкретными словами

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо подобрать регулярку для разделения текста на 4 абзаца(начиная от Issue заканчивая Affected Nodes).
Affected Nodes бывает 2-ух видов, иногда одного:

```
Issue 1: test
Summary: test
Solution: test
Affected Nodes: Internal 11.100.3.333 
Affected Nodes: External 33.33.333.333 (test)

Issue 2: test
Summary: test
Solution: test
Affected Nodes: Internal 11.100.3.333 

Issue 3: test
Summary: test
Solution: test
Affected Nodes: External 33.33.333.333 (test)

Issue 4: test
Summary: test
Solution: test
Affected Nodes: Internal 11.100.3.333 
Affected Nodes: External 33.33.333.333 (test)

Issue 5: test
Summary: test
Solution: test
Affected Nodes: Internal 11.100.3.333
```

Необходимо это для того, чтобы распарсить данные в модельку вида:

```
public class Issue
{
    public string IssueName { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string InternalNodes { get; set; }
    public string ExternalNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Показанный пример можно без регулярки через `.Split("\r\n\r\n")` или `.TakeWhile()` решить. Уточните, в чем именно проблема? Уточните формат входных и выходных данных.

Comment: мне необходимо получить массив из всех абзацев, для того, чтобы далее, опять же через регулярки, собрать модельки с полями "Issue", "Summary", "Solution", "Affected Nodes"

Comment: Это тоже можно сделать без регулярок. Дополните вопрос, его можно редактировать, покажите модель данных, в которую вы хотите распарсить этот текст.

Comment: добавил модельку

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/31RpXa

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Issue
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string IssueName { get; set; }
  public string Summary { get; set; }
  public string Solution { get; set; }
  public string InternalNodes { get; set; }
  public string ExternalNodes { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
  public static string GetText()
  {
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(), Console.InputEncoding))
      return sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
  
  public static void Main()
  {
    var issues = Regex.Matches(GetText(), @"Issue\s*(\d+):\s*([^\r\n]*?)\s*\r?\n(?:Summary:\s*([^\r\n]*?)\s*\r?\n|Solution:\s*([^\r\n]*?)\s*\r?\n|Affected Nodes: Internal\s*([^\r\n]*?)\s*\r?\n|Affected Nodes: External\s*([^\r\n]*?)\s*\r?\n)*")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => new Issue
      {
        Id = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value),
        IssueName = m.Groups[2].Value,
        Summary = m.Groups[3].Value,
        Solution = m.Groups[4].Value,
        InternalNodes = m.Groups[5].Value,
        ExternalNodes = m.Groups[6].Value,
      })
      .ToList();
    
    foreach (var x in issues)
      Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2,-6}   {3,-6}   {4,-12}   {5,-12}", x.Id, x.IssueName, x.Summary, x.Solution, x.InternalNodes, x.ExternalNodes);
  }
}
```

```
1   test   test     первая   11.100.3.333   33.33.333.333 (test)
2   test   test     test     11.100.3.333               
3   test   вторая   test                    33.33.333.333 (test)
4   test   test     test     22.211.4.444   33.33.333.333 (test)
5   test   test     test
```

Answer (score 0):

Если каждый абзац завершается двумя переводами строк, то подойдет такая регулярка:

```
(Issue[a-zA-Z0-9:.()\s]+?(?=\n{2}))
```